# Linux: cannot kill "Software & Updates" process

Tags: linux, debian, kill, software-update

Trying to do a software update, the corresponding program "Software & Updates" got stuck during the cache refresh.

How can I kill such a process? I looked at all the running processes with `su`, but I cannot find one with a name similar to the one I am looking for.

The interaction with the GUI (KDE) does not allow me to close the dialog (option disabled).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`xkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xkill) is likely to work here.  Just run the `xkill` command in a terminal (which I assume you can do, since you mentioned trying `su`), then click on the "Software & Updates" window.  `xkill` will forcibly close that window, which usually (but not always) triggers the underlying application to terminate.